# firewalld Not Registering Directives

Tags: postgresql, firewalld

I've sent some commands to `firewalld` to open up a `PostgreSQL` `port 5432` to be opened.  `nmap` shows it open on `localhost4` to be open, but on its ip `192.168.1.23` to be non-existent.

```
sniffing ports 0-10000 on 192.168.1.23...
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-18 12:12 EDT
Nmap scan report for neb.local (192.168.1.23)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
Not shown: 10000 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.19 seconds

sniffing ports 0-10000 on localhost4...
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-18 12:12 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost4 (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000060s latency).
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost
Not shown: 9999 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
5432/tcp open  postgresql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.18 seconds
```

I can't seem to get this port to be viewable on that IP, and open on another box (`192.168.1.24`).

```
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-07-18 12:37 EDT
Nmap scan report for neb.local (192.168.1.23)
Host is up (0.00034s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5432/tcp closed postgresql
MAC Address: D0:50:99:87:7B:4A (ASRock Incorporation)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.49 seconds
```

How can I get this to work?  Here are the `firewalld` instructions:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=postgresql
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port 5432/tcp
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-source=192.168.1.24
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-user1-rule='rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.24" port protocol="tcp" port="5432" accept'
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp0s25
  sources: 192.168.1.24
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client postgresql ssh
  ports: 5432/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
    rule family="ipv4" source address="192.168.1.24" port port="5432" protocol="tcp" accept
```

Comment: It looks like your PostgreSQL database is configured to only listen in 127.0.0.1, which is a common safe configuration for new installations. What is the current value of the `listen_addresses` parameter in your `postgresql.conf` file?

Comment: @telcoM And you are right again.  I thought I had set that.    And I've added my user to the `postgres` group, but I can't access `postgresql.conf` in a script due to `permissions`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This smells like a CTF exercise question, but I'm guessing you can probably use a combination of ````netcat```` and/or ssh tunnelling to achieve the desired effect. Either way if you're genuinely stumped, you'll probably get better answers on Information Security depending on their policy of handling CTF related questions.

Comment: Yeah I overlooked `postgresql.conf` `listen_addresses`.  I had a similar error before that confused me this time.